# Generar tests en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Intentando generar unos `test` en *Ruby*, en concreto en mi archivo _cliente_test.rb_ de este modo:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ClienteTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "no guardar un cliente sin nombre" do
    cliente = Cliente.new
    assert_not cliente.save
   end

  test "borrar cliente" do
    cliente = Cliente.take
    assert cliente.destroy
  end

 test "no repetir el nif" do 
    cliente1 = Cliente.new
    cliente2 = Cliente.new
    assert_not_equal(cliente1, cliente2, [msg])
 end

  test "guardar nuevo cliente" do
    cliente = Cliente.new
    assert cliente.save
  end

  test "editar cliente" do
    cliente = Cliente.take
    cliente.nombre = 'new'
    assert cliente.save
  end
end
```

Solamente me pasa el `test` de los dos primeros: no guardar un cliente sin nombre y borrar cliente. En los otros o bien me sale el siguiente error:

> Expected false to be truthy

O me dice en este caso:

> undefined local variable or method `msg'

¿Sabe alguien a qué se debe y cómo resolverlo? Me gustaría en realidad comprobar 3 cosas:

1. Que el cliente no se repita comparando el *nif*,
2. Comprobar que lo puedo editar y
3. Comprobar que lo puedo guardar.

Muchas gracias por vuestra atención. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Expected false to be truthy

Este mensaje simplemente dice que hay un `assert` que está devolviendo falso en lugar de verdadero; en el error te debe decir específicamente en qué prueba está el problema.

Por tu código, lo más probable es que el error esté en la prueba `"guardar nuevo cliente"`, en la cual generas un cliente nuevo pero sin dar más información (i.e. `Cliente.new`) por lo que muy probablemente no se esté guardando con `cliente.save` debido a alguna validación en el modelo `Cliente`. Para que puedas guardarlo, debes dar información a todos los atributos de acuerdo a las validaciones que tengas en el modelo.

> undefined local variable or method `msg'

En la prueba `"no repetir el nif"` tienes una variable (o método) `msg` que no has creado, justo en esta línea:

```
assert_not_equal(cliente1, cliente2, [msg])
```

Debes de crear la variable antes de utilizarla en esa línea, o bien, asignar el mensaje directamente (sin usar la variable):

```
test "no repetir el nif" do 
  cliente1 = Cliente.new
  cliente2 = Cliente.new

  assert_not_equal(cliente1, cliente2, "Error")
end
```

En tu ejemplo tienes `[msg]`, tal como se muestra en la documentación, pero eso únicamente indica que el mensaje es opcional, es decir, los corchetes no se utilizan.

> 1. Que el cliente no se repita comparando el nif

Primero tienes que crear *y guardar* un cliente con un `nif` específico y, después verificar otro cliente con ese mismo `nif`; ejemplo:

```
test "no repetir el nif" do 
  cliente1 = Cliente.create!(nif: 'A48265169')
  cliente2 = cliente1.dup

  assert_not cliente2.valid?
end
```

> 2. Comprobar que lo puedo editar

En lugar de verificar si puedes guardar el registro, debes verificar el contenido del atributo que has cambiado *después de guardarlo*; ejemplo:

```
test "editar cliente" do
  cliente = Cliente.take
  cliente.nombre = 'new'
  cliente.save

  assert_equal 'new', cliente.nombre
end
```

> 3. Comprobar que lo puedo guardar

Únicamente te falta proporcionar los atributos para que la validación no falle; ejemplo:

```
test "guardar nuevo cliente" do
  cliente = Cliente.new(nif: 'A48265169', nombre: 'Mantisa')
  assert cliente.save
end
```

---

**BONUS**

Puedes facilitar tus pruebas (y hacerlas más legibles) si utilizas `setup` para prepararlas:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ClienteTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # setup se ejecuta antes de cada prueba
  setup do
    @cliente = Cliente.new(nif: 'A48265169', nombre: 'Mantisa')
  end

  test "guardar nuevo cliente" do
    assert @cliente.save
  end

  test "no guardar un cliente sin nombre" do
    @cliente.nombre = ''

    assert_not @cliente.save
   end

  test "borrar cliente" do
    @cliente.save

    assert @cliente.destroy
  end

  test "no repetir el nif" do 
    @cliente.save
    cliente = @cliente.dup

    assert_not cliente.valid?
  end

  test "editar cliente" do
    @cliente.save
    @cliente.nombre = 'new'
    @cliente.save

    assert_equal 'new', @cliente.nombre
  end
end
```